# Ask data from user and store them inside a struct in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct, scanf, nodes

In the code below I tried to use printf and scanf to get data from user and store them inside a struct i defined called node.

The programme works fine for the first prompt, but as soon as the user input name, the programme ends with printing Age:salary:

Can anyone help me with this?

On a side note, can anyone also help me to understand how to create a loop to store data in various nodes and store them together? (Not hard-code it one by one)

Thank you very much!!

```
typedef struct node
{
    char *name;
    int age;
    int salary;
    struct node * next;
}node;

int main(void)
{
        node *tmp = malloc(sizeof(node));
        
        printf("Name:");
        scanf("%s", tmp->name);
        
        printf("Age:");
        scanf("%i", &(tmp->age));
        
        printf("salary:");
        scanf("%i", &(tmp->salary));
        
        tmp->next = NULL;
        
        free(tmp);
}
```

Comment: `char *name;` you need to allocate memory to write into

Comment: I spent effort on answering another of your questions. Then you deleted it without giving feedback. If you do that often people might stop answering your questions. So I hope that the deletion is only temporary, until you improved the question.

Comment: You totally misunderstood, the reason I deleted my question is because i saw your comment, and I realized I am making a mess in that question, therefore I deleted it. I apologize for that, I did not intend to do that. and really thanks for your answer in that question, but i still need to do a bit to digest the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You are trying to write to  Uninitialized memory

This is a very common problem beginners face.

You are trying to store the name using `char *name` declaration.
Here name does not point to a valid memory location, that's why You program is not running as expected.

Even if `name` points to a valid memory address, you must have enough memory allocated to store the data.

You can use

```
#define BUFFER_SIZE 50
char name[BUFFER_SIZE];
```

You can use any buffer size as you like, and then store a string of that length - 1 in the `name` array. `-1` is for the `null termination character` `\0`.

Using this declaration you are allocating memory of `BUFFER_SIZE` bytes and the `name` points to the first byte in that array.

**This allocation happens on the stack not in the HEAP**

Comment: Thank you!! solved now, but could you help me a little bit more by teaching me how to write some loop to get data from users and store them in a linked list? thank you very much anyways.

Comment: Glad to help, and for you question: At the end of collecting the data you can ask the user if he wants to enter more data, and then listen using `scanf`, if the answer is `n` you return. If it is `y` you allocate a new node using `tmp.next = malloc(sizeof(node))` and then `tmp = tmp.next`, and put this code in a while loop. You can also create a `node.previous` member and point it to the previous node. I am sure that there are a lot of articles and tutorials online, you can also use that to learn more.

Comment: Need some time to digest and try to write that in code, but anyways, really thank you for your help!!:)

Answer (score 2):

Use a char[] for name,
for example:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct node
{
    char          name[128];
    int           age;
    int           salary;
    struct node * next;
}node;

int main(void)
{
    node *tmp = malloc(sizeof(node));

    printf("Name:");
    scanf("%s", tmp->name);

    printf("Age:");
    scanf("%i", &(tmp->age));

    printf("salary:");
    scanf("%i", &(tmp->salary));

    tmp->next = NULL;

    free(tmp);
}
```

If you want to get several users, loop for ever and ask if the user wants to add more data.
I have create a function to print the list

Console:

```
Name:Foo
Age:12
salary:12
Continue Y/N
Y
Name:Bar
Age:14
salary:14
Continue Y/N
Y
Name:John 
Age:30
salary:45
Continue Y/N
N
John, 30, 45
Bar, 14, 14
Foo, 12, 12
```

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct node
{
    char          name[128];
    int           age;
    int           salary;
    struct node * next;
}node;

static void printList(node *n)
{
    while (n) {
        printf("%s, %d, %d\n", n->name, n->age, n->salary);
        n = n->next;
    }
}

static node *get_nodes(void) {
    node *list = NULL;
    while (42) {
        char c;
        node *tmp = malloc(sizeof(node));

        printf("Name:");
        scanf("%s", tmp->name);

        printf("Age:");
        scanf("%i", &(tmp->age));

        printf("salary:");
        scanf("%i", &(tmp->salary));

        tmp->next = list;
        list = tmp;
        printf("Continue Y/N\n");
        scanf(" %c", &c);
        if (c == 'N')
            break;
    }
    return list;
}

static void clearList(node *node) {
    if (node->next) {
        clearList(node->next);
    }
    free(node);
}

int main(void)
{
    node *list = get_nodes();
    printList(list);
    clearList(list);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! solved now, but could you help me a little bit more by teaching me how to write some loop to get data from users and store them in a linked list? thank you very much anyways.

Comment: Sorry, I almost missed your answer, thank you very much, sir!

Answer (score 1):

For fix your bug, you should allocate memory of your char *.

First Way, when you create your struct.

```c
typedef struct node
{
    char name[200]; // You specify that your char * can save 200 char
    int age;
    int salary;
    struct node * next;
}node;
```

or you can create init struct function

```
node *init_node()
{
   node *test = null;
   test->name = malloc(sizeof(char) * 200);
   test->age = 0;
   test->salary = 0;
   test->node = null;
   return test
}
```

Comment: I get what you are saying in the first half, but the syntax in the second half seems quite new to me, is there any topic I should study on?

Comment: the second part is just an function that you call and return a ```node * ``` with default value (int variable at 0, char * malloc, ...)